# Obtener el valor de un ítem en un array PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
$frutas = array(["Peras"] => "1200", ["Mangos"] => "3500", ["Manzanas"] => "7000");
```

Necesito obtener el precio del ítem "**Mangos**", y guardarlo en una variable. Ejm:

```
$mangos = 3500
```

Estuve intentando con la función **`array_search()`** de la siguiente manera, pero no funcionó:

```
$mangos = array_search("Mangos", $frutas);
```

Lo único que conseguí fue un `bool(false)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> array_search — Busca un valor determinado en un array y devuelve la
>   primera clave correspondiente en caso de éxito

Sabiendo esto, te está devolviendo `false` porque estás preguntando por "Mangos" y aunque este `string` se encuentre en el `array` no se trata de un *valor*, si no una *clave* por lo que no va a considerarlo.

No necesitas ninguna función para conseguir el valor del índice "Mangos", ya que al tratarse de un índice puedes acceder directamente a él:

**PHP**

```
$frutas = array("Peras" => "1200", "Mangos" => "3500", "Manzanas" => "7000");
$mangos = $frutas['Mangos'];

echo $mangos;
```

**Salida por pantalla:**

```
3500
```

**Referencia**: [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php)

Comment: Gracias @phpMyGuel por la ayuda!, olvidé comentar que necesito validar también si existe una clave o no en el array, por ejm: si en el array no existe "Mangos", entonces `$mangos = 0`... ¿Sabes cómo lo puedo hacer?. Gracias.

Comment: Ya intenté con **in_array()**, pero no funcionó... hice una condición anidada:
`$mangos = in_array("Mangos", $frutas)&&$frutas["Mangos"]!=""?$frutas["Mangos"]:0`, pero siempre me imprime 0

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con `if (isset($frutas['Mangos'])) { ... }`

Comment: Efectivamente, antes me salía un error undefined index 'Mangos'... pero creo que era porque hacía la condición dentro del var_dump...
Muchas gracias bro!

Comment: Si tratas de acceder a un índice inexistente el sistema te va a avisar con un *Notice*. La función `isset()` te evita acceder a un índice que no exista, por lo que el *Notice* no se va a generar.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa simple para este caso sería usar un [*operador ternario*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)  combinado con `empty`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$frutas = array("Peras" => "1200", "Mangos" => "3500", "Manzanas" => "7000");
$mangos = !empty($frutas['Mangos']) ? $frutas['Mangos'] : 0;
echo $mangos;
```

**Salida:**

```
3500
```

El *operador ternario*  es muy fácil de entender en este caso:

```
$mangos = !empty($frutas['Mangos']) ? $frutas['Mangos'] : 0;
```

- `$mangos` es la variable de asignación
- `!empty($frutas['Mangos'])` evalúa si la clave `Mangos` del array `$frutas` no está vacía. Hay que tomar en cuenta que colocar `!` delante equivale a preguntar en negativo: *si no está vacío...*
- Si la condición se cumple, o sea, si `$frutas['Mangos']` no está vacío, la variable adquirirá el valor que hay después de `?`
- En cambio, si la condición no se cumple, la variable de asignación adquirirá el valor que hay después de los dos puntos, o sea el valor `0`.

Hagamos una prueba con una clave (`Fake`) que no existe:

```
$mangos = !empty($frutas['Fake']) ? $frutas['Mangos'] : 0;
echo $mangos;
```

**Salida:**

```
0
```

Desde PHP 7 el código es todavía más simple, gracias al [Operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

Por ejemplo:

```
$mangos = $frutas['Mangos'] ?? 0;
echo $mangos;
```

**Salida:**

```
3500
```